# Agree and Continue Button is not coming in Magento 2.4 while installing

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

I am truing to install Magento 2.4 but problem is agree and continue button is not coming.

For Reference please find the attached image.

[image]

Thanks
SomuN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run below command in your command-line.

```
php bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://localhost/magento2 \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=magento2 \
--db-user=magento2 \
--db-password=magento2 \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=username@example.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1
```

In above command change url, username, db host, user, password based on your configuration and requirements. [link](https://www.kishansavaliya.com/magento2/how-to-install-magento-2-using-composer.html)

Hope this will help you.

Thanks.